# How to get word from JSON

Tags: angular, typescript

How could I get(("id"=) + 5 values) from JSON. JSON looks like:

```
{"html":"<div class=\"\" ng-reflect-dragula=\"second-bag\">
<!--bindings={\n  \"ng-reflect-ng-for-of\": \"[object Object],[object Object\"\n}-->
         <div id=\"1\" class=\"\" style=\"background-color: rgb(129, 205, 51)
```

As result I wanna get "id=\1\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx (regular expressions). Try this:

```
var myReg = new RegExp(/id="(\w+)"/, 'g');
var myArray = myReg.exec('{"html":"<div class=\"\" ng-reflect-dragula=\"second-bag\"><!--bindings={\n  \"ng-reflect-ng-for-of\": \"[object Object],[object Object\"\n}--><div id=\"123456789123456789\" class=\"\" style=\"background-color: rgb(129, 205, 51)');
```

This will give you a sort of an array:
`myArray[0]` will contain the whole matching expression, which is `id="value"`.
`myArray[1]` will contain the value itself.

You can learn more about regular expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

**EDIT**

To get multiple hits, run the `exec` method multiple times:

```
var myReg = /id="(\w+)"/g;
var str = 'test test id="123" test test id="456"';
var myArray;
while (myArray = myReg.exec(str)) {
    console.log(myArray[1]);
}
```

Notice that the regular expression can also be defined like this: `/id="(\w+)"/g`.

Comment: cool!
But could you tell me, how Could i get all id's...if I will have
'{"html":"<div class=\"\ id=\"1\" class=\"\"  id=\"2\" '

Comment: Did it suit your needs?

Comment: no...I think it is bad idea to convert HTML to JSON...So better use DOM

Comment: But did it answer your question?

Comment: It seems like...I do not remember